# Truncating SCM (git) URL for maven release tag push

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

For some reason, when running maven release, it is giving me an invalid URL just for the tagging part of the push. For the pom.xml commit/push, it works fine and goes to appropriate URL. See below:

```
[INFO] Working directory: /opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-parent
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd "/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-parent" && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-217365030.commit '/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-services/pom.xml' '/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-webapp/pom.xml' '/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-static/pom.xml' pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-parent
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd "/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-parent" && git symbolic-ref HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-parent
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd "/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-parent" && git push ssh://git@github.com/{org}/Section4362.git maven-release-test:maven-release-test
[INFO] Working directory: /opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace/section4362-parent
[INFO] Tagging release with the label section4362-parent-0.3...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd "/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace" && git tag -F /tmp/maven-scm-882610155.commit section4362-parent-0.3
[INFO] Working directory: /opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd "/opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace" && git push ssh://git@github.com/{org} section4362-parent-0.3
[INFO] Working directory: /opt/jenkins-home/jobs/Section 4362/workspace
```

You can see that for the push after the commit, it pushes to `ssh://git@github.com/{org}/Section4362.git` ({org} scrubbed by me), whereas for the push after the tag, it goes to `ssh://git@github.com/{org}` – URL should include `/Section4362.git` at the end. All my pom files specify the correct: `scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/{org}/Section4362.git`

How would URL be changing for tag push and where would it get it from? Build is obviously failing at that step saying unable to connect to repo.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. 
I use jdk 1.7, maven 3.3.9 and maven-release plugin 2.5.3

I took a look at the jira releated to this issue and I do not found that is was fixed  :-(

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-939

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-927

I found a trick so that maven do not troncate the url used for pushing the tag.

I precise both push and fetch SCM url in the pom.xml, using the same url. It is important to first define push url then fetch and not the opposite.
Here is an exemple.

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:git:https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/java-project-template-single-scm.git</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:git:[push=]https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/java-project-template-single-scm.git[fetch=]https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/java-project-template-single-scm.git</developerConnection>
<url>https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/java-project-template-single-scm.git</url>
<tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Comment: Nice workaround. The only other workaround would be to throw maven-release-plugin away and use only versions-maven-plugin and maven-scm-plugin like in : https://axelfontaine.com/blog/final-nail.html

Comment: Thanks you so much for documenting this workaround. I want to add the following:

If you have a connection like `scm:git:git@host:group:project.git` this trick doesn't work and the whole address explodes. In this case, switch to the ssh notation like `scm:git:ssh://git@host/group/project.git`. With this notation the push/fetch workaround can be applied: `scm:git:[push=]ssh://git@host/group/project.git[fetch=]ssh://git@host/group/project.git`. (Sorry if there are typos, I can't paste my client's actual URL here)

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue in maven-release-plugin which has to be fixed in order to get things working. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-767 for more details. Unfortunately, until the bug in git URL translation is resolved, not much can be done besides not pushing the changes to git.

Comment: Even though http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-767 is marked as FIXED, it still seems that it is an issue for many people and is not actually fixed.